# OR & AND Operators in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I want to achieve this in Elasticsearch.

```
select * from products where brandName = Accu or brandName = Perfor AND cat=lube(any where in any filed of an elastic search ).
```

I am using this query in Elasticsearch.

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "oil"
      }
    },
    "should": [
      {
        "term": {
          "BrandName": "Accu"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "BrandName": "Perfor"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

By this query m not getting the combination exact results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `minimum_should_match: 1` to your query and probably use `match` instead of `term` if your `BrandName` field is an analyzed string.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "oil OR lube OR lubricate"
      }
    },
    "minimum_should_match": 1,         <---- add this
    "should" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "BrandName" : "Accu"
      }
    }, {
      "match" : {
        "BrandName" : "Perfor"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple conditions in must also even if any one of the condition satisfy i need to hit the document.

Comment: {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [ {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "oil"
      }
    }, {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "lube"
      }
    }, {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "lubricate"
      }
    } ],
  "should" : [ {
      "match" : {
        "BrandName" : "Accu"
      }
    }, {
      "match" : {
        "BrandName" : "Perfor"
      }
    } ]
  }
}

Comment: I have the following scenario now,i have multiple must term and if any one of condition satisfies taht document should get hit.

Comment: I've updated my answer again to take into account your latest requirement

Comment: could you please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016092/search-with-synonym-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

This query satisfy your condition.

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : { "term" : { "cat" : "lube" } },
        "should" : [
            { "term" : { "BrandName" : "Accu" } },
            { "term" : { "BrandName" : "Perfor" } }
        ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
}
```