# Search with synonym analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the mapping i have used

```
"analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "synonyms_path": "D:\\MyElasticSearch\\elasticsearch-1.5.2\\config\\synonymsnew.txt",
              "ignore_case": "true"
            },
```

in this synonym file i have syonyms for **oil ,filter and engine**

oil, lubricate, lube

engine, motor, machine

filter, strainer, sifter

and here is my mapping

```
"ExtDesc": {
  "type": "string",
  "index": "analyzed",
  "index_analyzer": "synonym",
  "search_analyzer": "synonym",
  "fields": {
     "raw": {
        "type": "string"
     }
  },
  "copy_to": ["sym_words","did_you_mean"]
```

now when I search with term **cleaners** for this term there are no synonyms declared in the synonyms file.

when I search with the following query over all fields m getting hits null ,even though I have documents with cleaners text

```
GET synonympcdb3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "sym_words": {
        "query": "cleaners",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      }
    }
  }
}
```